# which is the best tool to develop UI for java application?

Tags: java, swing

I am new to java Swing and I need a tool to develop attractive window for my application.
I am expecting a tool similar to VB.Net, some thing which has drag and drop options.

Comment: I would recommend netbeans if you're after drag-drop gui building

Comment: @Sam: if you are looking for an Eclipse plugin you should state so in your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/). It comes out of the box with a GUI builder similar to Visual Studio's. [This](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html) quickstart should put you on the right direction.

EDIT: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942696/what-eclipse-gui-builder-plugin-do-you-suggest) previous SO thread in which some GUI building Eclipse plugins are discussed.

Comment: is there any plugin for **eclipse**...

Comment: @Sam: I have modified my answer. I have always used the Netbeans IDE and I have never had any issues with it. I'd recommend Netbeans but I have never used anything else really..

Comment: If you are used to eclipse learning netbeans won't be a problem. They remind alot of eachother

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson: I did/do use Eclipse, just not for GUI building. With regards to GUI Netbeans always did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

WindowBuilder is supposed to be nice https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/

And since it seems to matter for you: it is an Eclipse plugin

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Eclipse (Indigo) here's the plugin for WindowBuilder:
   http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.6

[image]

Answer (score 2):

NetBeans got a graphical Swing builder built in the IDE. However, many workplaces and schools don't let you install software on their computers which may require you to use Eclipse instead. For that you can install Google's open source plugin WindowBuilder which is quite neat and very simple to use.